# Groups containing a copy of $F_2$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group containing a non abelian free subgroup.
Is $G$ virtually torsion-free?

Comment: If we take the direct product of any torsion group with any nonabelian free group, we will get a non-torsion-free group. I don't understand your question.

Comment: I think that if the torsion group in your example is an infinite one then your example works! It's not virtually torsion free.

Comment: @mixedmath, you should make that an answer (!)

Comment: Could you add what "virtually torsion free" is?

Comment: Hyperbolic groups which are not virtually cyclic contain $F_2$ and are virtually torsion free.

Comment: @Rachmaninoff: A group $G$ is *virtually* $\mathcal{P}$, where $\mathcal{P}$ is some property, if $G$ contains a subgroup of finite index $H$ such that $H$ has $\mathcal{P}$. For example, all finite groups are virtually trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take the direct product of an infinite torsion group and any nonabelian free group, we get a virtually non-torsion-free group.